# Using Jenkins on git branch

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-deployment

I am alredy using jenkins to build my `master` branch. When `branch` is changed a Jenkins job is triggered and execute unit tests/integration tests/deliver.

I would like to trigger a Jenkins job to feature/hot-fix branches. The problem is that every time a developer creates a new branch, it has to create a new Jenkins job to be triggered when this branch is pushed.

I am using the github flow: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html

Is there anyway to automate this process?
How other teams are doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A [parameterized build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) where the branch name to build from is a parameter, that can then be triggered by the Jenkins API (straightforward POST to the trigger URL) from a [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) would achieve what you need.

Sidenote: It's useful just to see if the tests pass, but build trends, code coverage graphs, test result patterns and such lose their usefulness as you're comparing different branches.